# Traefik and existing AWS Classic Load Balancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik, amazon-elb, traefik-ingress

I have a working k8s cluster on EC2 with a classic load balancer (Port 443). Now I am trying to set up Traefik in my cluster, for which I am using the official helm chart. But I can't find a way to use my existing load balancer and prevent Traefik from creating its own load balancer.

How can I get Traefik to use the existing load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can change the service type to **NodePort** instead of the **Loadbalancer**

expose **nodeport** on trefik service accordingly

```
ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
      nodePort: 30081
```

Read more at : https://medium.com/@jainishshah17/use-pre-created-existing-loadbalancer-to-expose-your-kubernetes-service-407fb65cb416